# Menu with sub-items but without link

Tags: menus, buttons, add-submenu-page

while using WP you can change your main menu pretty easy. Still, when I want to create a new menu button, I have to give it a link to some article, category etc.

Is there a way to avoid it?

In wanted to made a menu with some buttons with sub-items, for example:

```
About us
> Team members
> Contact
```

I would like to make "About us" without being a link to anything - just a folder for "Team members" and "Contact". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a custom link with # instead of the page into the menu 
[image: custom link]
See in the attached screenshot

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! But is there a way for it to not be clickable at all? Right now you can still click it and resets the view position of the site.

Comment: Yes, you can make not clickable by this CSS code, put the CSS code in your CSS file

.inactiveLink {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}

please replace **.inactiveLink** by your class